# Is it okay to include the Delphi tag when asking a question about Inno Setup?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

I'm getting into using Inno Setup, which is not only based on pascal script, but is inspired by and built with Delphi. Not only that, but most Delphi developers use Inno Setup as a standard. I've been working with Delphi for many years now.

I have asked a couple questions so far with the [inno-setup](/questions/tagged/inno-setup) tag, but it seems they get little attention. If I were to add a [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) tag, many more people who know about it can see it - obviously increasing the possibility of an answer - even though it's not technically Delphi.

So can I add the [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) tag to [questions such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390996/inno-setup-properly-stop-service-before-file-copy)?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and add it and see what happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Do not do that, please. Inno Setup is based on custom Pascal Script language, which is syntactically same as Pascal but the language itself is different in many things (as you already know). That's similar as if you were adding e.g. [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags to [c](/questions/tagged/c) questions.

Yes. It has pretty low views (I know what I'm talking about) but there are few Delphi/Pascal people following this tag. And there are people who doesn't follow [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) tag but are very helpful for [inno-setup](/questions/tagged/inno-setup).

Of course there were (and probably are) some questions having both tags and it is upon you to try to get more attention this way, but it's a different language and I don't think it's good to do that, at least due to this language similarity it may lead to confusion of future visitors of such questions.

Comment: I agree totally. Delphi and Inno Setup Pascal Script share a lot, bot so do C and C++, or JavaScript and Java (or C# and Delphi, for that matter). The tags are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

As a hobbyist delphi developer who follows the delpi tag, I would say yes, add the tag.